# How to show hidden menus in breadcrumb component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm developing a breadcrumb component, one of the rules of the component is that if I have many items in the menu, I should only show the 1st, penultimate and last one menu. The rest of the menus must be hidden using the ellipsis symbol.

What I need to do is when I click on the ellipsis symbol it should open a small *window/modal* where it shows the hidden menus.

It's easier to understand with the image:

[image]
[image]

Can you tell me how to do this?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/breadcrumb-forked-2gxjvm?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";
import { ThemeConstants } from "./constants";
import Button from "./Button";
import Arrow from "./Arrow";

const { useState, useCallback } = React;

function Breadcrumb(props) {
  const { items, maxVisible } = props;
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const _items = items.slice();

  const handleHover = useCallback(() => setIsHovered(!isHovered), [isHovered]);

  const splitItemsAt =
    _items.length - maxVisible > 0 ? _items.length - maxVisible : 0;
  const overflowItems = _items.splice(0, splitItemsAt);
  
  const lastItem = _items.pop();

  const styles = getStyles();
  return (
    <div className={styles.box}>
      <Button label="My Files" shrink="0" />
      <OverflowItems items={overflowItems} type={props.type} />
      {_items.map((item, i) => {
        return [
          <Arrow key={`arrow-${i}`} type={props.type} />,
          <Button
            key={`btn-${i}`}
            label={item.label}
            shrink={isHovered ? 0.0001 : 25}
            onMouseOver={handleHover}
            onMouseOut={handleHover}
          />
        ];
      })}

      <Arrow type={props.type} />
      <Button label={lastItem.label} shrink={isHovered ? 0.0001 : 10} />
    </div>
  );
}

function OverflowItems(props) {
  const { items } = props;
  return items.length ? (
    <>
      <Arrow type={props.type} />
      <Button label="..." shrink="0" />
    </>
  ) : null;
}

function getStyles() {
  return {
    box: css`
      border: 1px solid ${ThemeConstants.colors.n60};
      padding: 16px;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex-direction: row;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      min-width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: flex-shrink 500ms ease-in-out;
      &:hover {
        flex-shrink: 0.0001;
      }
    `
  };
}
export default Breadcrumb;
```